# How to open a URL in any browser on any OS from a ruby CLI?

Tags: ruby, url, rubygems, command-line-interface

I am currently using Launchy and it works in my Mac terminal, however in my IDE's (tried in both gitpod and learn) I get an error saying 'unable to find browser command'. Is there a better method to do this? Or am I using launchy wrong?

Comment: These are sandboxed environments which don't provide a web browser.

Comment: So there is no conceivable way to give them access to any browser my computer is using?

Comment: No. A more accurate description might be that the code is running on a server in a virtual machine or docker container.

Answer (score 0):

In gitpod you can type `gp preview <url>` and it will open that url in a preview.
The command `gp url <port>` will give you the URL for a given port. 
E.g. if you have running a rails app in Gitpod on port 3000 you can type:

```
gp preview $(gp url 3000)
```

To open the website under development in a preview.